# Erlang Split a Tuple

Tags: erlang, tuples

I want to call map on a dict and get a list of their values back. Erlang doesn't have that built into the dict module, so here is how I'm getting around that:

```
Fn = fun(Tuple) ->
  [Key, Value] = Tuple,
  string:join([Key, Value], "=")
end,
lists:map(Fn, dict:to_list(Dict)).
```

The problem is that Key and Value are then getting assigned multiple times. How can I "split" the key/value tuple that is returned by `dict:to_list` inside of the anonymous function's call to `string:join`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm following what you're asking here. What do you mean by "Key and Value are assigned multiple times"?

When you say that you want to map over the dict and get a list of values back, do you mean values in the "Key-Value" sense?  In which case, you could do a this:

```
Values = [V || {_,V} <- dict:to_list(Dict)].
```

Which would just give you a list of the "value" side of the Key-Value nature of the dict.

You could also just get a list of keys by doing something similar.

```
Keys = [K || {K,_} <- dict:to_list(Dict)].
```

If you just want lists both Key and Values separated, you could use lists:unzip/1.

```
{Keys, Values} = lists:unzip(dict:to_list(Dict)).
```

Then `Keys` would be a list of all the keys, and `Values` would be a list of all the values.

Or are you concerned with the fact that `Key` and `Value` are both being assigned (as in variable assignment) for each member of your dict?  If so, don't. Those assignments are fast and are just pointers, not memory copies.

Answer (score 3):

As you have a list of tuples with a lists as values maybe you're looking somthing like this:

> [string:join ([K, V], "=") || {K, Values} <-
>   dict:to_list(Your_dictionary), V <- Values].

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Relative newcomer who's never tackled the dict module before, but this seems to work for me:

```
dict:fold(fun(Key, Value, Accum) ->
                  [Value | Accum] end, [], D).
```

Example:

```
init() ->
    Dict = dict:new(),
    Dict2 = dict:append(key, value, Dict),
    Dict3 = dict:append(key2, value2, Dict2),
    dict:append(key3, value3, Dict3).

grab_values(D) ->
    dict:fold(fun(Key, Value, Accum) ->
                      [Value | Accum] end, [], D).
```

Invoked:

```
4> D = dictfold:init().
{dict,3,16,16,8,80,48,
      {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
      {{[],[],
        [[key2,value2]],
        [[key3,value3]],
        [],[],[],[],[],
        [[key,value]],
        [],[],[],[],[],[]}}}
5> dictfold:grab_values(D).
[[value2],[value3],[value]]
```